# Include device information in "Export Ids"

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

In the Crashlytics tab in the Fabric dashboard, I can filter issues by device and OS. However, when I click on an issue it seems that I see all issues for all devices and OSes, and when I export IDs I get all IDs, not filtered, and don't get any device information in that list. Is there a way to get just the IDs for the devices and OSes for which I filtered, or to include device and OS information in the exported IDs?

We don't have Answers/Events setup, so that information isn't there. We also don't have any custom keys for sending Android device information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. No, there is not a way to apply the OS and Device filters to the list of User Ids currently. Will let the team know you'd like this added.